# ActiveRecord builds instance of wrong class through a scope targeting an STI class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, polymorphic-associations, arel, sti

I would like to be able to call the `build` method on a scope that targets a certain class of model via its STI type, and have ActiveRecord build an instance of the correct class.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :discount, where(type: 'DiscountLineItem')
end

class DiscountLineItem < LineItem; end

> LineItem.discount.build # Expect an instance of DiscountLineItem here
=> #<LineItem ...>
```

Here, I expected an instance of `DiscountLineItem`, not an instance of `LineItem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though ActiveRecord doesn't instantiate the object as the right class, it does set the type correctly. You basically have two ways around this:

1) Create the object and then reload it from the database:

```
item = LineItem.discount.create(attrs...)
item = LineItem.find(item.id)
```

2) Use the STI class and build the object directly from it:

```
DiscountLineItem.build
```

With all that ActiveRecord can do, this does seem like kind of a senseless limitation and might not be too hard to change. Now you've piqued my interested :)

**Update:**

This was recently [added to Rails 4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/89b5b31cc4f8407f648a2447665ef23f9024e8a5) with the following commit message:

> Allows you to do BaseClass.new(:type => "SubClass") as well as
>   parent.children.build(:type => "SubClass") or parent.build_child to
>   initialize an STI subclass. Ensures that the class name is a valid
>   class and that it is in the ancestors of the super class that the
>   association is expecting.

Comment: Perhaps it's time, then, to move this discussion into the Rails tracker. I'll write up a failing test case, and post it today.

Comment: I coded up a fix last night and was going to post it to the rails core google group for feedback. I'll post it here as a update later this evening when I get a chance.

Comment: @steveluscher Here's a patch for ActiveRecord that you might want to try: https://gist.github.com/5cad22a11f011052d8f6

Comment: Would you like to submit that to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7021 @beerlington? I've written up that failing test and referenced it there.

Comment: @steveluscher Looks like the issue got closed :/. If that's the expected behavior, it'll be hard to convince people to change it. You can use one of the options I suggested or feel free to take the patch I wrote and use it in your app or create a gem with it. Also, it was based on Rails 3.2.6 so I don't know if it will work in 4.0.

Comment: @steveluscher Good news, looks like someone's pull request got accepted for this. I updated my answer for anyone who stumbles on this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `build` for a moment. If you have some `LineItem` `l` and you do `l.discount` you're going to get `LineItem` instances, not `DiscountLineItem` instances. If you want to get `DiscountLineItem` instances, I suggest converting the scope to a method

```
def self.discount
  where(type: 'DiscountLineItem').map { |l| l.becomes(l.type.constantize) }
end
```

Now you will get back a collection of `DiscountLineItem` instances.

Comment: That should be `def self.discount`

Comment: I like the concept, but using map will kill your ability to chain any other scopes or methods since you're converting the ActiveRecord::Relation object to an array. There has to be a way to do this cleanly :/

Comment: Yup, I just need to read docs on converting it back to a relation.

Comment: Ooh. Though this technique end-of-lifes the `ActiveRecord::Relation`, stopping my ability to chain, thank you for pointing out the `becomes` method.

Comment: Yeah, its one of those methods you knew you were looking many times with your polymorphic work for but didn't know what to search for to find it. I'm looking more into an alternative solution to keep the relation, but have a feeling (with my current rails knowledge) its going to end up pretty hack-ish.