# Single table inheritance scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

Is it possible to set-up a scope on a single table inheritance that returns the subclass?

For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sticky, -> { where(type: 'StickyPost') }
end

class StickyPost < Post
end
```

Now, when I call `sticky` on a collection of posts I get a collection of `StickyPost` instances.

But when I call `posts.sticky.build`, the `type` is set to `StickyPost`, but the class still is `Post`.

```
posts.sticky.build
=> #<Post id: nil, message: nil, type: "StickyPost", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**Update**

Apparently this works.

```
posts.sticky.build type: 'StickyPost'
=> #<StickyPost id: nil, message: nil, type: "StickyPost", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Which is strange, since the scope already sets the type, it seems a bit redundant. Any way to set this behaviour in the scope?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387836/activerecord-builds-instance-of-wrong-class-through-a-scope-targeting-an-sti-cla

Comment: Why you want it to build with Posts? and not with StickyPost.new?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Comment: @techvineet Because I am working with a collection, and until a certain point I don't know whether to use `StickyPost` or another subclass.

Comment: @lol007 Yes `Post.new type: 'StickyPost` works. Strange that it doesn't work through the scope, since it also sets the type.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect @lol007 his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `sticky` scope return the correct class by using `becomes` method in the scope:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sticky, -> { where(type: 'StickyPost').becomes(StickyPost) }
end
```

The `becomes` method maps an instance of one class to another class in the single-table inheritance hierarchy. In this case, it maps each instance of `Post` returned by the `sticky` scope to `StickyPost`. With this change, calling `posts.sticky.build` will now return an instance of `StickyPost`:

```
posts.sticky.build
=> #<StickyPost id: nil, message: nil, type: "StickyPost", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: This seems to fail with `undefined method "becomes" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
 ...`, since `becomes` is an instance method, not a class method.